# Host header attack in Liferay

Tags: liferay-7

To prevent the Host header attack in liferay, there is a virtual.hosts.valid.hosts = localhost, 127.0.0.1, liferaytest.com, liferaytest1.co setting
However, the hosts that host my server are changing, is there a variable that is responsible for the current host, and we will change dynamically

Answer (score 0):

The setting that you found, clearly says:

> Input a list of comma delimited valid domains and IPs that the portal is allowed to use.
>
> ```
> virtual.hosts.valid.hosts=*
> ```

With the given default, any hostname is allowed, so `*` is the variable that you're looking for.

If you have well-known administrative hosts, or hosts that mustn't be accessed from certain networks, endpoints or reverse proxies, you can configure there what must not happen. Or implement filters that contain your custom logic.

In general: If you don't know upfront what's allowed, you'll need to allow everything. You might want to elaborate on "the host header attack" that you want to prevent, because apparently you want to explicitly allow any host.